# Is there a way to get all the forms of a scope?

Tags: angularjs

If I have more than one form attached to a scope, is there a way to go trough all of them without knowing all their names?

I want this so I can ask users if they want to navigate away without saving changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to check out the constructor names of `$scope` properties and if one equals to `FormController` then you know it is a form. Something like this:

```
function findForms() {        
    angular.forEach($scope, function(item){             
       if(item && item.constructor.name == 'FormController'){
          console.log(item);
       }
    });
}
```

There is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WrJLu/).

Answer (score 1):

You could check all objects on your $scope to see if they have a `$addControl` function which is specific to forms:

```
angular.forEach($scope,function(item){
       if(item &&  typeof(item.$addControl) != "undefined"){
          console.log(item);
       }
});
```

See [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/muMYGbq3SQWMPlLfyLko?p=info).